# Recursive Fortran subroutines and interfaces

Tags: fortran, fortran95

Do I need to define an interface for recursive Fortran95 (and above)  subroutines? In a library, does it make a difference if the subroutine is exported to the user?

Comment: What do you mean by "define an interface".  Do you mean, "must there be an explicit interface when such a procedure is referenced?"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: You should always provide an explicit interface (best using a module, NOT an interface block!) so that the user does not have to do it himself, but IIRC it is not strictly necessary here.

Comment: I have copied the things which require an explicit interface on reference in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31630662).  As you can see, `recursive` is not there.  But it's still a good idea to offer one.

Comment: Thanks francescalus, that's about what we needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RECURSIVE is not an attribute that requires an explicit interface, as it doesn't affect how the procedure is called. For more information on explicit interfaces, see an article I wrote a while back on the topic: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/01/05/doctor-fortran-gets-explicit-again